# Continuous check for VPN Connectivity - Python

Tags: python

Is there any efficient way to check and report in a log file or on the console may be... when ever the VPN is disconnected?

```
import time
print time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
```

Can print the time but I do not know what is the code to recursively find whether the VPN is active or not. Pinging it in a while(1) would be a stupid way to check if the connection is active or not. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: You might get more responses if you accepted answers on some of your past questions. Anyway, sending a packet from one computer to the other and receiving it back is the ONLY surefire way to check if the connection is active. However, your VPN software might already be doing this, and so you might be able to hook into APIs or eventing systems there. However, you haven't provided us details on what VPN software you're using, so we can't tell you if there are such abilities.

Comment: Mark, I am sorry. I will now accept a solution in my previous threads but I do vote up the useful answers though. Anyways, I am using VMWare vSphere CLient. Does that help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the product, unfortunately. The easiest way would still be a ping, in my opinion. It would not even depend on your VPN client used. Just make sure to have your script sleeping for a few seconds between pings so you're not sending out packets as fast as you can. Perhaps someone with more knowledge of the client software can provide more insight, however.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I shall wait for some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is system dependent, I do know that it works on Linux because I've done something similar, but not sure about Windows though. I don't know if you want a solution not involving ping, but I think this is a good solution.

```
import logging, os, time

PING_HOST='10.10.10.10'  # some host on the other side of the VPN

while True:
    retcode = os.system('ping -c 1 %s' % PING_HOST)

    if retcode:  
       # perform action for lost connection
       logging.warn('Lost visibility with %s' % PING_HOST)

    time.sleep(10)  # sleep 10 seconds
```

This works because ping returns a return code of `0` for success. All other return codes signify an error.

Comment: Hey thanks, I just tried it out in my Windows machine and it says `NameError: name 'logging' is not defined` I am using simple print instead though as of now

Comment: logging is a module, so if it is not installed any call to it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

In case the IP of vpn changes, you can check if a tunnel has been established at all.

```
import psutil
import logging, os, time
import subprocess
import sys

procname = "yourprocess_name"

while True:
    cmdout = subprocess.Popen(["ifconfig | grep tun"],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
    print "cmdout: "+str(cmdout)
    time.sleep(2)
    #-----
    if "tun" in cmdout:
        print "seems to be ok"
    if not "tun" in cmdout: 
        # perform action for lost connection
        print "killing "+str(procname)
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            # check whether the process name matches
            print "Listing procname: "+str(proc.name())
            if proc.name() == procname:
                proc.kill()
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: I am trying to use this code to see if vpn is connected for me. What should procname be here?

Answer (score 0):

This method uses the NAME of the HOST "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" associated with your IP (Mostly the corporation's VPN):

```
import os
import platform
def check_ping():
   hostname = "xyz.com" #hostname will be..Name under: "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" when you type "ipconfig" in cmd..
   response = os.system("ping " + ("-n 1 " if  platform.system().lower()=="windows" else "-c 1 ") + hostname)
   # and then check the response...
   if response == 0:
       pingstatus = "Network Active: Connected"
   else:
       pingstatus = "Network Error: Not Connected"

   return pingstatus
response = check_ping()
print(response)
```